# ROS2 equivalents to ROS1 roscd, rosmsg rossrv

Tags: ros, ros2, roscd, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there equivalent commands for `roscd`, `rosmsg` and `rossrv` (especially for `rosmsg show`), `rosed`, `rosls` and `rosmv`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358573/ros2-equivalents-to-ros1-roscd,-rosmsg-rossrv.../) by [screen33](https://answers.ros.org/users/40664/screen33/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2020-08-03

Post score: 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are equivalents for some of them. In ROS 2 they're all under the `ros2` command.

---

### rosmsg / rossrv

The equivalent to `rosmsg/rossrv` is `ros2 interface`.

```sh
$ rosmsg show std_msgs/Bool
bool data
```

ROS 2 equivalent

```sh
$ ros2 interface show std_msgs/msg/Bool
bool data
```

and for services

```sh
$ rossrv show std_srvs/Trigger
---
bool success
string message
```

ROS 2 equivalent

```sh
$ ros2 interface show std_srvs/srv/Trigger
---
bool success   # indicate successful run of triggered service
string message # informational, e.g. for error messages
```

And `ros2 interface` also works with actions

```sh
$ ros2 interface show test_msgs/action/Fibonacci
#goal definition
int32 order
    ---
#result definition
int32[] sequence
---
#feedback
int32[] sequence
```

---

### rosed / roscd / rosls

In ROS 1 I think these were provided by `rosbash`: http://wiki.ros.org/rosbash

```sh
$ rosls std_msgs
cmake  msg  package.xml
```

There's nothing equivalent in ROS 2 that I know of. Maybe you could make a bash alias around `ros2 pkg prefix`?

```sh
$ ls `ros2 pkg prefix --share std_msgs`
cmake  environment  local_setup.bash  local_setup.dsv  local_setup.sh  local_setup.zsh  msg  package.dsv  package.xml
```

---

Here's a brief intro to the command line tools.
https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Introspection-with-command-line-tools/

If you'd like to contribute to them, most of the source code is in the `ros2cli` repo: https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli . Some tools are in other repos; for example `ros2 launch` is in the ros2/launch_ros repo: https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/tree/master/ros2launch

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [screen33](https://answers.ros.org/users/40664/screen33/) on 2020-08-05**:
Yes `alias ros2cd="ros2 pkg prefix"` works but is not as handy as the original roscd: Autocompletion does not work and `ros2cd` alone either. Since we're in a Python subprocess, it can't work the same. Maybe opening a subshell? Not sure that would be nice though.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-08-05**:
`ros2 pkg prefix <tab>` does provide completion of all available package names. For a custom alias you will need to register the completion function yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An equivalent to `roscd` is provided by `colcon-cd` - see https://github.com/colcon/colcon-cd/

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-08-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2